# Google Bigquery table alias was working one day, now giving an error

Tags: google-bigquery

I was running the following query below yesterday, and it was working fine. Now everytime I run it, it says, "Table all has no field user_id"

```
select
  all.user_id,
  UTC_USEC_TO_YEAR(timestamp) as time,
  sum(amount) as amount
from foo.bar as all
join (select user_id, max(version) as max_version from foo.bar group by user_id) as latest
on all.version = latest.max_version and all.user_id = latest.user_id
group by all.user_id, time;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday we turned on a subtle schema validation change we've been trying to turn on for several weeks now. It will enable us to allow schema evolution (e.g. adding columns to a table) in the future, which is something that customers have been asking for. It looks like this change had an unintended side-effects, however. I'll revert the change until can we make sure that it doesn't hit this issue.

Comment: FYI ... this change has been rolled back pending investigation, so your original query should work. Please let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting,

On a whim, I prefixed all the columns like this and it works. It was working yesterday too, so there's some glitch in the Matrix

```
select
  all.user_id,
  UTC_USEC_TO_YEAR(all.timestamp) as time,
  sum(all.amount) as amount
from foo.bar as all
join (select user_id, max(version) as max_version from foo.bar group by user_id) as latest
on all.version = latest.max_version and all.user_id = latest.user_id
group by all.user_id, time;
```

If someone from the bigquery team can comment why, that'd be great.